# Nested forms in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

You can find a Plunker demonstrating the Problem here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyfOIZPqkaSHfY5Js3xw?p=preview)

I want to use nested forms in AngularJS. To do that it seems like `ng-form` is the way to go and i tried the following:

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="ctrl.form1()">
    <button type=submit>Form1</button>
    <ng-form novalidate ng-submit="ctrl.form2()">
        <button type=submit>Form2</button>  
    </ng-form>
</form>
```

While I expected the inner submit to execute the submit-action of the inner form, instead the method `form1()` is called everytime when i click either button.

Why does it behave like this and how can i achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:
>   * ngSubmit directive on the form element
>   * ngClick directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit])

Visit [Angular Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

```
    <form novalidate>
        <button type=submit ng-click="ctrl.form1()">Form1</button>
            <ng-form novalidate >
               <button type=submit ng-click="ctrl.form2()">Form2</button>  
            </ng-form>
    </form>
```

see working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0UOFF98S92e2u53v8Qt3?p=preview)